# Sonata User Advanced Configuration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I am trying to configure the advanced configuration of the SonataUser Bundle(https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/3-x/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html).

After following the documentation I get the following errors on installing assets:

1. [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jms_serializer" (in /var/www/html/SonataProject/app/config/config.yml). Looked for
   namespace "jms_serializer", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "fos_use
   r", "sonata_core", "sonata_block", "knp_menu", "sonata_doctrine_orm_admin", "sonata_admin", "sonata_easy_extends", "sonata_user", "debug", "
   web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in /var/www/html/SonataProject/app/config/config.yml (which is being imported from "/var/www/html/Sonat
   aProject/app/config/config_dev.yml").

   After I comment out `jms_serializer` configuration, I get another error:
2. [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]
   Invalid type for path "sonata_user.profile.dashboard.blocks.position". Expected array, but got string

Here is my config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
#        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
#        auto_mapping: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

#FOSUser Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager

    profile:
        # Authentication Form
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager

#SonataUser
sonata_user:
    security_acl: false
    manager_type: orm

    table:
        user_group: "my_custom_user_group_association_table_name"

    impersonating:
        route:                page_slug
        parameters:           { path: / }

    class:
        user: Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group: Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group

    admin:                  # Admin Classes
        user:
            class:          Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle

        group:
            class:          Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\GroupAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle

    profile:
        # As in SonataAdminBundle's dashboard
        dashboard:
            groups:

                # Prototype
                id:
                    label:                ~
                    label_catalogue:      ~
                    items:                []
                    item_adds:            []
                    roles:                []
            blocks:
                type:                 ~
                settings:

                    # Prototype
                id:                   []
                position:             right
        register:
            # You may customize the registration forms over here
            form:
                type:                 sonata_user_registration
                handler:              sonata.user.registration.form.handler.default
                name:                 sonata_user_registration_form
                validation_groups:

                    # Defaults:
                    - Registration
                    - Default
            # This allows you to specify where you want your user redirected once he activated his account
            confirm:
                redirect:
                    # Set it to false to disable redirection
                    route: 'sonata_user_profile_show'
                    route_parameters: ~

        # Customize user portal menu by setting links
        menu:
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit', label: 'link_edit_profile', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit_authentication', label: 'link_edit_authentication', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}

        # Profile Form (firstname, lastname, etc ...)
        form:
            type:               sonata_user_profile
            handler:            sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]

# override FOSUser default serialization
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            - { path: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/config/serializer/FOSUserBundle, namespace_prefix: 'FOS\UserBundle' }    

#SonataAdmin    
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
```

Any ideas??

**EDIT**:

For the second error I tried editing the `sonata_user.profile.dashboard.blocks` as follows:

```
blocks:
                type:                 ~
                settings:
                    position:             right
                    # Prototype
                id:                   []
```

I am not sure if this is correct configuration but the error goes away.

Awaiting response!

Comment: Found the solution to my first error. Just needed to add `new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),` to my AppKernel.php

Comment: Still stuck on the second error though

Answer (score 0):

Look at the doc the position is indented differently :

```
blocks:
            type:                 ~
            settings:

                # Prototype
                id:                   []
            position:             right
```

In yours, position is just under the id... Might be that

Comment: Thanks for the input. However this was the hit n trial edit I made. I don't know if thats the correct way, but the error goes away. Also I tried the way it is given in the docs but it gives me error